# Sort UITableView content (Address Book) alphabetically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, abaddressbook

Below is what I am using to retrieve the contacts list from the device. I want it to be displayed alphabetically but using other examples seen on stack overflow I have been unable to get it to work.
The code below is from a tutorial, what do I need to do to it to sort according to alphabetical order?

```
- (void)getPersonOutOfAddressBook
{
    //1
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

if (addressBook != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Succesful.");

    //2
    NSArray *allContacts = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

    //3
    NSUInteger i = 0; for (i = 0; i < [allContacts count]; i++)
    {
        Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
        ABRecordRef contactPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allContacts[i];
        //4
        NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson,
                                                                              kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        NSString *lastName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
        NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];

        person.firstName = firstName; person.lastName = lastName;
        person.fullName = fullName;

        //email
        //5
        ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonEmailProperty);

        //6
        NSUInteger j = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(emails); j++) {
            NSString *email = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, j);
            if (j == 0) {
                person.homeEmail = email;
                NSLog(@"person.homeEmail = %@ ", person.homeEmail);
            }
            else if (j==1) person.workEmail = email; 
        }

        //7 
        [self.tableData addObject:person];
    }

    //8
    CFRelease(addressBook);
} else { 
    //9
    NSLog(@"Error reading Address Book");
}
}
```

This is my UITableView code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Identifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

Person *person = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = person.fullName;

return cell;
}
```

I have tried below

```
[self.tableData sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

I have also tried `NSSortDescriptor` but I don't have a Key to sort by.

Comment: What's missing is the code to do the sorting, what have you tried?

Comment: @SteveWilford amended original post to be more clear, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to sort the array of `Person` objects. Once you have finished adding them all to the array you can sort on the `fullName` using the following code:

```
[self.tableData sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Person *p1, Person *p2) {
    return [p1.fullName compare:p2.fullName];
}];
```

**Alternative**

You may want to implement a `compare:` method on the `Person` object and perform the comparison there, this will keep sorting logic nicely encapsulated and ensure that anything else that uses `Person` objects can easily perform sorts without duplicating the code shown above.

```
@implementation Person

// Mostly likely this implementation will contain more code, not shown for brevity

- (NSComparisonResult)compareByFullName:(Person *)otherPerson {
    return [self.fullName compare:otherPerson.fullName];
}

@end
```

Then you can sort the array with:

```
[self.tableData sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareByFullName:)];
```

Comment: Great answer, although it will probably more useful to compare lastName (and possibly firstName afterwards) than fullName to get a sorting behaviour that aligns with usual expectations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement and provide a method to sort a Person record as a selector for the sortUsingSelector method invocation.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it like this.

//keys with fetching properties NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey]; CNContactFetchRequest *request = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc] initWithKeysToFetch:keys];

//Order contacts by Surname. request.sortOrder = CNContactSortOrderFamilyName;

--OR YOU CAN--

//Order contacts by Name. request.sortOrder = CNContactSortOrderGivenName;